# How to use If condition in self join for a table with multiple columns maintaining hierarchy

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, left-join, self-join

I have two tables. And I am trying to use self join on table on different fields. Below are the tables available and required output.

```
1. Table 1:  time_setting

cid pid   fid    time
4   220   1138    40
4   220   NULL    30
4   NULL  NULL    70

2. Table 2: file_params

fid    pid    cid
1138   220    4
1139   220    4
1140   220    4
1141   221    4
```

I want below output:

```
fid    tat
1138   40
1139   30
1140   30
1141   70
```

As 1138 `fid` is matching `tat` taken as 40.
`fid` 1139 and 1140 is not matching in table `time_setting` but its `pid` is matching so `tat` taken 30 and for `fid` 1142 `pid` is not matching but `cid` is matching so `tat` taken as 70.

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT fid,pid,cid,tat FROM
(SELECT t1.fid,t2.`pid`, t3.cid,
IF(t1.`fid` IS NOT NULL,t1.`tat`,
IF(t1.`fid` IS NULL AND t2.pid IS NOT NULL,t2.tat,
IF(t1.`fid` IS NULL AND t2.`pid` IS NULL,t3.tat,0)))
 AS tat FROM 
`file_param` p
LEFT JOIN `time_setting` t1 ON (t1.fid = p.fid)
LEFT JOIN `time_setting` t2 ON (t2.pid = p.pid)
INNER JOIN `time_setting` t3 ON (t3.cid = p.cid)
WHERE p.cid = 4) tbl GROUP BY fid,pid,cid
```

but not getting expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want cascading left joins and conditional logic:

```
select fp.fid, coalesce(ts1.time, ts2.time, ts3.time) tat
from file_param fp
left join time_setting ts1 on ts1.fid = fp.fid
left join time_setting ts2 on ts2.fid is null and ts2.pid = fp.pid
left join time_setting ts3 on ts3.fid is null and ts3.pid is null and ts3.cid = fp.cid
```

Comment: Thank you for your try but it is giving time for only matching fid ie. 1138 for other fid its giving NULL value

Comment: Thank you @GMB , your answer helped me to find correct output, I have shared working query below. Thank You once again :)

Comment: @Madhura: I fixed the typos. Consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below query is now working for me :

```
SELECT fp.`fid`, COALESCE(ts1.`tat`, ts2.`tat`, ts3.`tat`) tat
FROM `file_param` fp
LEFT JOIN `time_setting ` ts1 ON ts1.fid= fp.fid
LEFT JOIN `time_setting ` ts2 ON ts2.fid IS NULL AND ts2.`pid` = fp.`pid`
LEFT JOIN `time_setting ` ts3 ON ts3.`fid` IS NULL AND ts3.`pid` IS NULL AND ts3.`cid` = fp.`cid`
WHERE fp.`cid` = '4'
```